Writing a socket server for an API that uses a persistent connection
I'm asked to create an app to manage a device that's usually behind a NAT or firewall, so unreachable from the outside.
Fortunately, the device's creators thought of that, so they created an API that connects to an outside server and keeps the connection alive while also receiving requests over the same connection - if I understood the manual. The device in question is a Videosec face recognition device, protocol is called "LAPI" (v1 or v2), and all I could find about the protocol is here: http://videosec.com/support/Firmware/oet/OET-213H_API-JSON.pdf
Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I receive the heartbeat request as soon as I turn on the device, but I don't know if it acknowledged my HTTP 200 response, and any request I send is not met - just ignored by the device which keeps sending heartbeats.
My question is - am I doing this right? Do I understand the HTTP keep-alive (persistent) connections enough? Here is my server socket code. It's in PHP, but I also tried Python:
<?php
header_remove();
$host = "(public ip)";
$port = 5196;
set_time_limit(0);

if (!extension_loaded('sockets')) {
    die('The sockets extension is not loaded.');
}

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

function getLocalTime()
{
        $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Belgrade'));
        return $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

function returnok($spawn, $url = "/LAPI/V1.0/PACS/Controller/HeartReportInfo")
{
        $rsobj = [
                "ResponseURL" => $url,
                "Code" => 0,
                "Data" => [
                        "Time" => getLocalTime()
                ]
        ];
        $resobj = json_encode($rsobj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . PHP_EOL;
        $response = "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok" . PHP_EOL;
        $response.= "Content-Length: " . strlen($resobj) . PHP_EOL;
        $response.= "Content-Type: application/json" . PHP_EOL;
        $response.= "Connection: keep-alive" . PHP_EOL;
        $response.= "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" . PHP_EOL;
        $response.= $resobj . PHP_EOL;
        echo $response;
        if (!socket_write($spawn, $response, strlen($response))) {
                echo "Could not write output\n";
        }
}

function writeback($spawn, $url, $method = "GET")
{
        $output = $method . " " . $url . " HTTP/1.1" . PHP_EOL;
        $output.= "Content-Type: application/json" . PHP_EOL;
        $output.= "Connection: keep-alive" . PHP_EOL;
        $output.= PHP_EOL;
        echo $output;
        if (!socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen($output))) {
                echo "Could not write output\n";
        }
}

$spa = true;
while ($spa) {
        $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        if ($input = socket_read($spawn, 16 * 1048576)) {
                $input = trim($input);
                if ($spawn) {
                        returnok($spawn);
                        sleep(7);
                        writeback($spawn, "/LAPI/V1.0/PeopleLibraries/BasicInfo");
                } else {
                        $spa = false;
                }
        }
    socket_close($spawn);
}

socket_close($socket);
?>

This is what's exchanged:
RECV: POST /LAPI/V1.0/PACS/Controller/HeartReportInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: (redacted):5196
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 180
Connection: keep-alive

{
"RefId": "(redacted)",
"Time": "2011-12-01 00:38:07",
"NextTime": "2011-12-01 00:38:37",
"DeviceCode": "(redacted)",
"DeviceType": 1
}

SEND: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 108
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
{"ResponseURL":"/LAPI/V1.0/PACS/Controller/HeartReportInfo","Code":0,"Data":{"Time":"2024-11-26 02:09:06"}}

SEND: GET /LAPI/V1.0/PeopleLibraries/BasicInfo HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive

RECV: POST /LAPI/V1.0/PACS/Controller/HeartReportInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: (redacted):5196
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 180
Connection: keep-alive

{
"RefId": "(redacted)",
"Time": "2011-12-01 00:38:16",
"NextTime": "2011-12-01 00:38:46",
"DeviceCode": "(redacted)",
"DeviceType": 1
}

SEND: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 108
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
{"ResponseURL":"/LAPI/V1.0/PACS/Controller/HeartReportInfo","Code":0,"Data":{"Time":"2024-11-26 02:09:15"}}


Bidirectional HTTP over a single socket seems fairly unusual – it's certainly a custom Videosec invention beyond standard HTTP "persistent connection (keep-alive)" – but:
You are missing a blank line in between your request/response headers and body.  The parser needs to know where the headers end; this is indicated by two consecutive line breaks. For example:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 108
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{"ResponseURL":"/LAPI/V1.0/PACS/Controller/HeartReportInfo","Code":0,"Data":{"Time":"2024-11-26 02:09:15"}}

This applies even to requests or responses without a body (and/or without headers); they still must end with a blank line.
(I doubt you need X-Frame-Options: here, as the response is not going to a web browser, so there are no "frames" in this sense. Similarly, your GET requests don't need a Content-Type: because they have no content; typically only responses or POSTs need this header. A GET that wants to receive JSON would use Accept: to indicate that.)
Also: Do not use PHP_EOL in this situation. That constant is meant to be platform-specific, which is the exact opposite of what you want for network protocols. For example, HTTP is specified to use CR+LF (\r\n or \x0D\x0A) line breaks regardless of the platform (some servers happen to accept bare LF, others don't).

Thank you! That was very informative. Only after I posted the question I read the HTTP RFC and realized that I've been an idiot for using PHP_EOL, but same thing happens with /r/n. I'll try to implement your other suggestions now. I agree it's fairly unusual, but I have been able to trace it back to something called "CrowdSec" (https://docs.crowdsec.net/u/user_guides/lapi_mgmt) which "VideoSec" is probably trying to clone. I'll add this to my question.
